# VideoView doesn't follow Activity's orientation configuration

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a simple activity which plays a short video, It works great except for the video orientation: I've locked the orientation of the activity to portrait and it works so when the VideoView start playing the video.However, after few seconds it seems that the VideoView/MediaPlayer doesn't follow the orientation of the activity in which it is located.

Note, that the Activity is not recreated, the video changed its own configuration during playback.

**EDIT:**

This orientation changed cause when I try to finish this activity via another background activity's AsyncTask, note that I've tried to do it with startActivityForResults(...) .. finishActiviy(...). As well as sending an Intent (Single_top) which should ask the activity to finish itself. NOTE that FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT doesn't change the orintation
Here is the code is used to lock the orintation (non of them had worked)

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //OnCreate
android:screenOrientation="portrait" //manifest
android:screenOrientation="portrait" //layout
```

Here is the code I used to play the video, activity:

```
protected onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    .
    .
    .
    videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +          getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video));
    videoHolder.start();
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have your checked the video file?

Comment: I doubt that the issue still relevant for new versions of android, but I certainly did check the video file